Vertices and vertex color misaligned
I'm trying to read vertex positions of a mesh and combine with the right vertex color to recreate it in Unity.
This is how I combine vertex position with vertex color using the vertex.index in the color_attribute. When I look at the length of the vertices I get 24 but the length of the color attribute is always 36 for a cube, so I guess I'm doing something wrong when querying the vertex color with vertex.index in the attribute list, causing the colors to "misalign" with the correct vertex.
        meshVertice = []
        meshColor = []

        color_layer = mesh.color_attributes.data.vertex_colors.active
        for vertice in mesh.vertices:
            worldVertice = obj.matrix_world @ vertice.co
            meshVertice.extend([worldVertice.x,worldVertice.y,worldVertice.z])

            if color_layer:
                color = color_layer.data[vertice.index].color
                meshColor.extend([0, int(color[0] * 255), int(color[1] * 255), int(color[2] * 255)])

Blender, one side is vertex painted black:

Unity recreated mesh:

It goes even worse if I edge split the mesh in Blender:


Blender Stack Exchange is not a bug hunting site. Try blenderartists.org or Discord for example. Here you should ask about a specific problem e.g. how to properly export vertex color to unity using fbx format. Your attempt may then serve as an addition to help understand your problem, as long as you don't post any AI-generated code which is likely to be misleading instead.

You're probably confusing vertex domain against face corner domain. A cube has 6 faces, each 4 corners = 24 attribute elements in face corner domain. Vertices are shared (8), but splitting faces makes each vertex have exactly one corner. Triangulating doubles the number of faces, so now you have 12 faces, each 3 corners = 36 corners. Using vertex index to access face corner or vice-versa will yield nonsense.

Thank you @MarkusvonBroady I understand the problem and I know that using vertex index will yield nonsense, but I've googled forever and cannot figure out how to go about it. I've used all the different loops to get the information, but it always boils down to comparing to the mesh vertices and aligning with that. Can you point me in a direction or give a hint.

You can convert your attribute between face corner and vertex domains.

Thank you @MarkusvonBroady I will look into that!

Converting the color_attribute to vertex instead of corner fixed it.

